# Schema Master, Schema, Scheme - table name/design help

Tags: sql-server, database-design, naming-convention

I’m stuck! 3 table names.

**Schema Master, Schema, Scheme.**

They are too confusing for me I always get them mixed up....

Any ideas on how to name better?

I also maybe designing this database incorrectly but I'm really struggling to come up with any other way to handle multiple schemas, especially when custom ones per team will start popping up.

I also want to try and be clever and maybe other the just industry sectors also include `Country > Region A > Region B` or maybe something like `Equity > Global Equity > European Equity > Germany Equity`.

I'm working in MSSQL.

**Schema Master**

```
BICs
GICs
ICB
```

**Schema**

```
GICS Level 1, parent - NULL
GICS Level 2, parent - GICS Level 1
etc...
```

**Scheme**

```
GICS, Level 1, energy, parent - NULL
GICS, Level 2, coal, parent - energy
```

etc

This is a diagram for GICS. What i'm trying to avoid is having to design/create a table for each schema and then tables for each level. I think it can be handled using the method above.

[image]

Comment: Does each schema have sectors, industry groups, industries and sub-industries? If so, that's your tables right there. I don't see anything wrong with that. Alternatively, you can create a single table with categories and implement a parent-child relationship. I think the first approach is best to be honest.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I guess what I was thinking about here is then trying to be clever and including not just sectors schema but things like Country, Region A, Region B or Equity > Global Equity > European Equity

Comment: If your types can be anything, then a parent/child hierarchy would be best. But it is very inflexible in terms of varying columns.

Comment: Thanks, I think i'm going against good database design here allowing types to be anything.

Comment: Maybe an RDBMS is the wrong technology for you. You may be better off using a NoSQL solution such as MongoDB which allows the schema to be as dynamic as you need it to be.

Comment: I’m just so foreign to NoSQL. I wish I knew it better

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90788/discussion-between-mr-brownstone-and-glenn-sampson).